# How to reference a NodeJS module w/ Webpack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, webpack, systemjs

When using SystemJS for writing an Angular2 app I can do a

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
  'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
  '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
  'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
};
```

to tell angular where to find things when I call a `import {} from`. In this case if I wanted to use RxJS now I could `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'`.

But what would the equivalent of this be if I were using [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack does that automatically. Unless you are using code splitting. 
Suppose you have:
Module A:
`import {fn} "moduleB"`

Module B:
`export default fn`

Webpack will include all the dependencies of module A (your entry), so you will be able to use fn.
Now if you use code splitting, you will need to use **require.ensure**
e.g:

```
require.ensure(["module-a", "module-b"], function(require) {
    var a = require("module-a");
    // ...
});
```